# CSV string is being trimmed while importing with OleDb

Tags: vb.net, csv, oledb, trim

I am reading csv file with oledb mechanism. My main issue is that the string values inside csv while reading are being trimmed (both: at the beggining and and the end with white spaces). I have some specific data in csv file which needs to have such white spaces in only some cases - that's why i cannot handle that after being processed. It has to be done with the convertion.

Unfortunatelly it has to be done with oledb and vb.net as our complex mechanism is based on those technologies.

Is that possible to find a hack or workaround that oledb will not trim my strings?

Below is my code, actual results and expected:

csv file:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4
Text1 | Text2| Text3 |Text4
```

schema.ini

```
[test.csv]
Format=Delimited(|)
Col1=Column1 Text
Col2=Column2 Text
Col3=Column3 Text
Col4=Column4 Text
```

Code

```
Private conn As New OleDbConnection
Private cmd As New OleDbCommand
Private myAccessDataReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = Nothing
Sub Main()

    Try
        Dim dirInfo As String = "C:\csv"

        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If

        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & dirInfo & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;"";"
        conn.Open()

        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * From [test.csv]", conn)

        myAccessDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If myAccessDataReader.HasRows Then
            myAccessDataReader.Read()
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("|" + myAccessDataReader.Item("Column1") + "|")
        Console.WriteLine("|" + myAccessDataReader.Item("Column2") + "|")
        Console.WriteLine("|" + myAccessDataReader.Item("Column3") + "|")
        Console.WriteLine("|" + myAccessDataReader.Item("Column4") + "|")
        Console.ReadKey()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Actual Results:

```
|Text1|
|Text2|
|Text3|
|Text4|
```

Expected Results:

```
|Text1 |
| Text2|
| Text3 |
|Text4|
```

Ps. I have tried with different settings in schema.ini: encoding, MaxScanRows, fixed width, but nothing helped.

Comment: I don't see the Format specified in the connection string: `Extended Properties="text;HDR=YES;FMT=FixedLength"`. Then, as you already know, you *must* use a schema.ini.  [Text File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/text-file-format-text-file-driver), [Schema.ini File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-drive).

Comment: @jimi the format is in the schema file.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fb09b0c-21de-4eea-8deb-937c98ad6a4b/getting-test-strings-from-csv-data-source?forum=vststest

Comment: If you are going to read the entire file and make no query to it then I would suggest to just read the file to a datatable. OLE DB CSV has ansi padding ON and not work around.

Comment: @brax you completely destroyed the OP's output.

Comment: can you re-post your output please. Someone is just reformatting everything without paying attention.....too busy trying to get reputation points

Comment: @Chillzy i just rolled it back.

Comment: @Chillzy  Yep, I can manage to be cryptic at times. Let's try it again :). The only way I know, is to have fixed-length fields. If they can be fixed, those spaces won't be trimmed. In delimited fields, I don't have knowledge that it can be achieved. AFAIK, spaces will be trimmed. (Can't you really load those csv in a List?)

Comment: If you are creating the csv file yourself, you could try to put the fields with spaces inside double quotes: `|"Text1 "|" Text2"|" Text3 "|`. Not sure if this would fix it though.

Comment: The spaces are trimmed because of the ANSI padding used by OLE DB. On a regular SQL server you would be able to set this to off but not reading a csv. Reading the file and make your own reader ain't that hard.

Comment: I know that it is not hard to make it done in other way. My question was rather is it possible to do it with standard oledb reader as i need to pass oleDbConnection as method parameter to plenty of methods.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a general issue with trailing spaces when dealing with database: some char data types use spaces to fill the rest of the characters. For MSSql there is an option ANSI PADDING which you can turn ON/OFF, but I don't see a way to set that for Microsoft JET Engine which we use for CSV files; we support both oledb and odbc and this issue exists for both.

So, the answer is you can't. Trailing spaces will be always removed when you import data from a CSV data source, no matter if you define text/char/memo data type for your columns (e.g. using schema.ini) or enclose strings into double quotes. You can put some special character (non-space) in the end, after space(s), such as tab, for instance.

[microsoft website](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fb09b0c-21de-4eea-8deb-937c98ad6a4b/getting-test-strings-from-csv-data-source?forum=vststest)

Answer (score -1):

Try this out.....but there's no guarantee since I haven't put any error handling....

```
Function ReadCSVToTable(ByVal Schema As String) As DataTable
    Dim file As New StreamReader("C:\dump\" & Schema)
    Dim CSVName As String = file.ReadLine()
    CSVName = Strings.Mid(CSVName, 2, CSVName.Length - 2)
    Dim Delimiter As String = file.ReadLine
    Delimiter = Strings.Mid(Delimiter, Strings.InStr(Delimiter, "(") + 1, Delimiter.Length - Strings.InStr(Delimiter, ")") + 1)
    Dim Buffer As String = ""
    Dim xtable As New DataTable
    xtable.TableName = CSVName
    'create table
    Do
        Buffer = file.ReadLine
        Dim xCol As New DataColumn
        With xCol
            .ColumnName = Buffer.Split("=")(0)
            .Caption = Buffer.Split("=")(1).Split(" ")(0)
            Select Case Buffer.Split("=")(1).Split(" ")(1).ToLower
                Case "text"
                    .DataType = GetType(String)
                Case "integer"
                    .DataType = GetType(Integer)
                Case "decimal"
                    .DataType = GetType(Decimal)
                Case "boolean"
                    .DataType = GetType(Boolean)
                Case Else
                    .DataType = GetType(String)
            End Select
        End With
        xtable.Columns.Add(xCol)
    Loop Until file.EndOfStream = True
    file.Close()
    file.Dispose()


    'Fill the table
    file = New StreamReader("C:\dump\" & CSVName)
    'skip header
    Buffer = file.ReadLine
    Do
        Buffer = file.ReadLine
        Dim xCol(xtable.Columns.Count - 1)
        Dim xCount As Integer = 0
        For Each tCol As DataColumn In xtable.Columns
            Select Case tCol.DataType
                Case GetType(String)
                    xCol(xCount) = Convert.ToString(Buffer.Split(New String() {Delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None)(xCount))
                Case GetType(Integer)
                    xCol(xCount) = Convert.ToInt64(Buffer.Split(New String() {Delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None)(xCount))
                Case GetType(Decimal)
                    xCol(xCount) = Convert.ToDecimal(Buffer.Split(New String() {Delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None)(xCount))
                Case GetType(Boolean)
                    xCol(xCount) = Convert.ToBoolean(Buffer.Split(New String() {Delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None)(xCount))
                Case Else
                    xCol(xCount) = Convert.ToString(Buffer.Split(New String() {Delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None)(xCount))
            End Select
            xCount = xCount + 1
        Next
        xtable.Rows.Add(xCol)
    Loop Until file.EndOfStream = True
    file.Close()
    file.Dispose()
    Return xtable
End Function
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim CSVTable As DataTable = ReadCSVToTable("schema.ini")
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but i have mentioned that oledb connection is mandatory as it is used as parameter later in other methods.

Comment: @Arsey have fun then. I guess you haven't read the post from microsoft

Comment: @Arsey I'll leave the code as it might be useful for others. you didn't have to vote it down. you can leave a message instead

Comment: @Arsey you know if you use some of the imagination you have and save the data table to let's say a MS access DB and use your ole connection to the access db to pass to your other methods. I don't even see the purpose of having spaces in the front to start with. I would understand you want to keep them at the end....